# Flutter Camera Preview not rotating with phone orientation

Tags: android, camera, orientation, flutter

I'm new to Dart/Flutter and currently using the Flutter [Camera Plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera) but I am running into a problem with the CameraPreview for when the phone turns to landscape mode.  The images stay vertical and don't rotate the 90degrees with the phone.

I have tried countless things including Transform.rotate(), but I can't seem to get the image to both, fill the screen and rotate 90degrees.

The pictures that were taken while the phone was sideways still saved in the correct orientation when I view them, but using the _cameraPreviewWidget.

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsAab.jpg)

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0YE.png)

Comment: im getting the same issue, will update if i find a solution

Answer (score 7):

Adding **SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations()** to my initState() & dispose() functions solved this problem for me.

```
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);    
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: This is not a perfect solution, This is a hacky solution.

Comment: It works for me. If you have a better suggestion, I'll be happy to test it.

Answer (score 4):

A package call camera_camera https://pub.dev/packages/camera_camera 
has do great work and provide great feature you can reference his source code or fork directly.

about rotate issue, please use this package https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation 
and wrap body like this

```
return Scaffold(
      body: NativeDeviceOrientationReader(builder: (context) {
        NativeDeviceOrientation orientation =
            NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
```

you can reference full code at 
https://github.com/marslord/camera/blob/master/lib/cam.dart ,this is not camera_camera package and author use RotateBox

```
return RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: turns,
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: 1 / controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: CameraPreview(controller),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

camera_camera package use this at line 76

```
return NativeDeviceOrientationReader(
  useSensor: true,
  builder: (context) {
    NativeDeviceOrientation orientation =
        NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
```

about fit screen issue 
camera_camera package do this with below code full code is here https://github.com/gabuldev/camera_camera/blob/master/lib/page/camera.dart

```
    return widget.mode ==
              CameraMode.fullscreen
          ? OverflowBox(
              maxHeight: size.height,
              maxWidth: size.height *
                  previewRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(
                  bloc.controllCamera),
            )
          : AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: bloc
                  .controllCamera
                  .value
                  .aspectRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(
                  bloc.controllCamera),
            );
```

execute result of camera_camera package can found on his github

execute result of https://github.com/marslord/camera 
[image]

both check with real device and works

official camera plugin example rotate image can work with combine Native_device_orientation
and RotateBox , you can reference https://github.com/marslord/camera/blob/master/lib/cam.dart 
but official camera plugin example fit screen issue will need to modify layout code

I would suggest use camera_camera's method,  Stack CameraPreview and Button. it looks more like Native Camera App and easy to maintain landscape mode

official camera plugin example rotate image code snippet with combine Native_device_orientation and RotateBox

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Camera example'),
      ),
      body: NativeDeviceOrientationReader(builder: (context) {

        NativeDeviceOrientation orientation =
        NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);

        int turns;
        switch (orientation) {
          case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:
            turns = -1;
            break;
          case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:
            turns = 1;
            break;
          case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitDown:
            turns = 2;
            break;
          default:
            turns = 0;
            break;
        }

        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: turns,
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1 / controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: Center(
                          child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate your phone while using a camera the preview will stay vertical, however when you view the image it will be in landscape, try with the default camera app and it would be the same

You can obviously rotate your UI that is on top of the camera preview when the phone rotates

Answer (score 1):

My solution;
using with this libraries; https://pub.dev/packages/image and https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation

```
 Future<void> takeAPicture()async{
pictureShooting=true;
final XFile image=await cameraController!.takePicture();
img.Image? _capturedImage=img.decodeImage(await image.readAsBytes());

final NativeDeviceOrientation currentOrientation=await _nativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator.orientation(useSensor: true);

switch(currentOrientation){
  case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight: _capturedImage=img.copyRotate(_capturedImage!, 90);break;
  case NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:   _capturedImage=img.copyRotate(_capturedImage!, 270);break;
  case NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitDown:   _capturedImage=img.copyRotate(_capturedImage!, 180);break;
  default:
}

takenImage=Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(_capturedImage!));

pictureShooting=false;
showImageApprovalScreen=true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a real Android device in Landscape orientation would show the appropriate camera preview content, but because the device wasn't "allowed" to rotate (due to app manifest/plist settings), it was showing as a strip where the Left to Right wide pixels were showing in a rectangle on the left side going from Bottom to Top, where that rectangle was small in order to fit in that dimension... so most of the screen was white empty space.  On emulators, this phenomenon didn't occur (rotation worked as desired).  The solution, after much searching and troubleshooting was to put some code in to modify what orientations were allowed, only while the camera preview was being displayed:

```
//allows any rotation (while camera preview is open)
Future<void> _enableRotation() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  ]);
}

// may block rotation; sets orientation back to OS defaults for the app
Future<void> _backToOriginalRotation() async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([]);
}
```

I used `await _enableRotation();` in initializing an ancestor of `CameraPreview` and I used `await _backToOriginalRotation();` in disposing.
I used `WillPopScope`'s `onWillPop` callback and `await Navigator.of(context).maybePop<String>>(filepath);` to close the view when a picture had been captured (and after the image had been saved to temp directory at the path `filepath`), so that the Android back button would also run the dispose and rotation code via `onWillPop`.

EDIT: After testing on both iOS and Android actual devices, this fix worked on Android phones, but did not work on iPhones.  iPhones still displayed the camera preview in a small rotated strip when the device is landscape.  This is using camera package version `0.8.1+7`.

EDIT2: After updating the iOS info.plist to allow any device orientation, this approach worked for iPhones too.  However, there are still devices and situations where the preview orientation (and thus captured image orientation) are incorrect, leading to about 50% of captured landscape photos being saved sideways (in portrait orientation).  Reproduction of the problem seems possible if you start your device in landscape orientation when you open the camera preview and don't rotate your device before capturing (or if device auto-rotate screen setting is off).

Answer (score 0):

```
class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializePlayer();
  }

  Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
// widget.url put url video file path
    _videoPlayerController =
        _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);
    await Future.wait([_videoPlayerController.initialize()]);
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

  bool useSensor = true;
  bool portrait;

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NativeDeviceOrientationReader(
      builder: (context) {
        NativeDeviceOrientation orientation =
            NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
        portrait = orientation == NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp;
        if(orientation == NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft){
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
            !portrait
                ? DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
                : DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
            !portrait
                ? DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
                : DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
          ]);

        }else{
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
            !portrait
                ? DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
                : DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
            !portrait
                ? DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
                : DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
          ]);
        }
        return _chewieController != null &&
                _chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
            ? Chewie(
                controller: _chewieController,
              )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
      useSensor: useSensor,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).